Deploy ECS Image to existing Application Load Balancer with CDK
I am trying to deploy an ECS Image to an existing Application Load Balancer with CDK. We want to deploy this to an existing ALB and VPC.
// Reference existing ALB
const alb =
  elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.fromApplicationLoadBalancerAttributes(
    this,
    "ImportedALB",
    {
      securityGroupId: "sg-XXXXXXXX",
      loadBalancerArn:
        "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:listener/app/alb-appliance/XXXXX/XXXXX",
    }
  );

// Create higher level construct containing the Fargate service with a load balancer
new ecspatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
  this,
  "amazon-ecs-sample"
  {
    loadBalancer: alb,
    cluster: cluster,
    circuitBreaker: {
      rollback: true,
    },
    memoryLimitMiB: 512, 
    cpu: 256,
    assignPublicIp: false,
    desiredCount: 1,
    taskImageOptions: {
      image: image,
      containerPort: 80,
      logDriver: ecs.LogDrivers.awsLogs({
        streamPrefix: id,
        logRetention: logs.RetentionDays.ONE_YEAR,
      }),
    },
  }
);

When I run a CDK diff I see the following error message:
Error: Can only call addTargets() when using a constructed Load Balancer or an imported Load Balancer with specified vpc; construct a new TargetGroup and use addTargetGroup
    at ApplicationListener.addTargets (C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\cdk-workshop-ts\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-elasticloadbalancingv2\lib\alb\application-listener.js:1:5736)
    at new ApplicationLoadBalancedServiceBase (C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\cdk-workshop-ts\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ecs-patterns\lib\base\application-load-balanced-service-base.js:1:3657)
    at new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService (C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\cdk-workshop-ts\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-ecs-patterns\lib\fargate\application-load-balanced-fargate-service.js:1:601)
    at new ECSServiceStack (C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\cdk-workshop-ts\lib\cdk-workshop-ts-stack.ts:43:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\cdk-workshop-ts\bin\cdk-workshop-ts.ts:7:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Documents\GitHub\cdk-workshop-ts\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users \Documents\GitHub\cdk-workshop-ts\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)

What settings do I need to modify to resolve this error message?
I am using an ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService with this ECS image.

Can you post the code that produces the error (how are you using the imported ALB?) and the full error message?

Also you left out the actual error message. What you've provided is the stack trace.

I have added the code that uses the ALB and updated the Error message to show the initial message correctly.

It's telling you it doesn't know which VPC the load balancer is on. So it can't create the cluster, service, and task, in the right VPC where the load balancer can access them.
You should specify your VPC in fromApplicationLoadBalancerAttributes. For example:
const alb =
  elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.fromApplicationLoadBalancerAttributes(
    this,
    "ImportedALB",
    {
      securityGroupId: "sg-XXXXXXXX",
      loadBalancerArn:
        "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:listener/app/alb-appliance/XXXXX/XXXXX",
      vpc: ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "ImportedVpc", { vpcName: "my-vpc" })
    }
  );


I added the vpc from look-up and now see this "Error: Cannot retrieve value from context provider vpc-provider since account/region are not specified at the stack level.  " The account and region are already specified on the stack.
